# Just found a hemorrhoid. Should I lift this friday?

Tags: strength-training, injury, health, stronglifts

I'm 23 and god only knows how this could've happened. It could either be from the other day when I got trigger happy and evacuated my bowels quickly(I wasn't bearing down hard I just push it all out relatively quickly and with ease)or from squatting and deadlifting. I've been doing stronglifts 5x5 for a few months and had some trouble making gains until I really started to push myself.

I'm afraid that the extra exertion I've been putting into my lifts has played a role in the formation of this. But should I continue to lift tomorrow? I want to say that I put a lot of pressure in my ass as I exert the force on the squat, because everyone always says to squeeze your glutes. Could that have been the cause?

My lifting stats really aren't even that high:

OHP: 100
Squat: 225
DL: 225
BP: 180
Rows: 100

Comment: I have also face similar issue. Mine was because I tried to squat more weight than I could handle and my breathe went haywire - I exhaled when squatting down and then gulped in between. I have read somewhere that pushing the air downwards when squatting weights can cause hemorhhoids. I found that strengthening core helped get rid of it but it relapses if I get sedentary and spend too much time sitting.

And I so agree by what Berin said about role of breathe in providing core stability..

Comment: @christopher-bruce What happened in the end? What advice did your doctor give and did you lift and continue lifting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1:** consult a doctor to determine:

1. If it's really [hemorrhoids](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/hemorrhoids-topic-overview)
2. The severity if it is
3. And the protocol to remedy it.

If the hemorrhoid was caused by lifting, then know it won't get any better if you continue lifting the way you do.  You can work through minor hemorrhoids, but refine your technique.

**Step 2:** fix your form

You'll find that you need to keep a rigid body to perform the lifts well.  However, you may be misunderstanding the intent behind the cues you hear or read.

***"Squeeze the [Glutes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluteus_maximus_muscle)"***

This cue is not talking about squeezing the cheeks together.  It is referring to engaging the gluteal muscles for the purpose of standing back up with a loaded bar.  It's more about hip extension than it is sphincter control.

Perhaps a better cue for you would be to "get tight".

***Increase overall tightness***

The first thing to master is how to breath for lifting.  A proper breath will help brace your body better and complete the lift without endangering yourself.  The following steps are applicable to squat and bench press, with only slight modifications needed for deadlift:

1. unrack the bar (not necessary on deadlifts)
2. Inhale into your spine.  You should have equal pressure all the way around your core
3. Hold that breath until exertion is over.  For the squat and bench, that's down and up.  For deadlift that's until you are in the upright position or when the bar is back on the ground.

The purpose of that breath is to provide core stability.  It not only helps you lift more weight, it also helps the rest of your musculature do what it is supposed to do.

Getting tight also affects your posture.  The upper back is braced and ready for the pull, squat, or press.  Same with the abs, legs, hip muscles, etc.  The more rigid you can make your body in a good posture, the more you'll be able to lift.

Comment: Wouldn't holding your breath cause hemorrhoids?

Comment: Not necessarily.